# cannot import name 'InceptionResNetV1' from 'facenet_pytorch'

Tags: google-colaboratory

I installed 'facenet_pytorch' moudle, but when I run this code on colab:

```
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResNetV1
```

I receive this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'InceptionResNetV1' from 'facenet_pytorch' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/facenet_pytorch/__init__.py)
```

can anyone help?

Comment: The answer to your question is here: https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch/blob/master/models/inception_resnet_v1.py Look very closely at the class name in the code. You have incorrectly capitalized a letter in your import statement, which is why it isn't recognizing the name. It should be `InceptionResnetV1`, with a **lowercase "n."**

Comment: tnx a lot. u r right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tnx for the answer of @Quack E. Duck

```
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1
```